# How to play sound in Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, sound

I want to play the sound on Wolfram Cloud.

```
Sound[Table[SoundNote[i,0.1,"Violin"],{i,0,12}]]
```

The Wolfram Cloud Public address is as follows.

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/9d6b7eb0-762b-4abd-ab68-f9eabd58724a

But the sound doesn't play.
Is there no sound support on wolfram cloud?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Unfortunately, however, it does not play on Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/20e1fe9c-7688-4ecf-bbd9-16392e728250

Does the sound play when I press the button?

Comment: https://www.wolframcloud.com/env/20e1fe9c-7688-4ecf-bbd9-16392e728250

If you change "obj" to "env" in the URL, it will play on that page.

Comment: In other words, the URL for "private folder (env)" plays well, but the URL for "public folder (obj)" does not play well.